# not able to apply git

Tags: git, pycharm

I am trying to make a seo program. for that i need git. but there is no git sub-folder when i try to apply git from settings>version control>git

i have searched on google as well but didnt get proper answer. Please tell me a way to get a sub folder of git

Comment: "I am trying to make a seo program. for that i need git." False...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to initialize Git for your project in pycharm. Here's [how to do that](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/set-up-a-git-repository.html?section=Windows%20or%20Linux#e9d6e46b):

> Import an entire project into a single Git repository
>
> 1. Open the project that you want to put under Git.
> 2. From the main menu, choose VCS | Enable Version Control Integration.
> 3. In the dialog that opens, select Git from the drop-down list and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do it with command line,

1. Make sure latest version of [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) is installed on your machine.
2. Open command prompt, cd to your project directory
3. type `git init` in console.

And boom, your project is now being tracked by git. Git init will create a .git folder in your project directory. To ignore certain files from git tracking, add a [.gitignore file](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore).